# TikZ - xy-shifting and use of let

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have three questions about the code below.

1. I fail to use an xy-shift : see the final `(2-2)++(6pt,2pt)`. What is the standard way to achieve this?
2. The code is not one of mine. I don't understand the meaning of `\p1` and `\x1`. The rest of the code is no mystery to me. ;-)
3. How to just use 80% of `\x1` for the radius?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

$det = \begin{NiceArray}{ccc}
    u &           & v       \\
    x & \kern.1pt & x'      \\
    y & \kern.1pt & y'
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix|{2-1}{3-3}|
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (2-2.north) 
           -- 
           node[red,circle,inner sep=1pt] (minus) {$-$} 
           (3-2.south);
           
     \draw [red,->] 
           let \p1=($(minus.east)-(minus.center)$) in
           (2-2)++(-6pt,2pt) 
           to[out=0,in=150]
           (minus.60)
           arc[start angle=60,end angle=-240,radius=\x1]
           to[out=30,in=180] 
           (2-2)++(6pt,2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
= ...$

\end{document}
```

This gives the following unwanted output.

[image]

Comment: You probably want `([shift={(6pt,2pt)}]2-2)` at the end. Doing `(foo) ++ (bar)` is a move to operation from foo to foo + bar. It *is not* (foo + bar). You need to do either the `shift` as above or use `calc` again: `($(2-2)+(6pt,2pt)$)`.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd comment does the job. Thanks for clarifying the use of `++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are a number of [path operations](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths) available with TikZ.

   The most common are `--` (a straight *line to*), `-|` and `|-` as well as `.. controls ..` and the special `to` (also `edge` but that's even more special).

   However, there is one more:
   That's right, nothing: A *move to*.

   When you write

   ```
   \path (<coordinate>);
   ```

   you already instruct TikZ to *move to* `<coordinate>`.

   Now the Pluses (`+` and `++`) aren't part of the path operation, they are part of the [coordinate specification](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.4). Here we differentiate between

   1. one `+(<coordinate>)` which describes a coordinate that is *relative* to the last absolute coordinate and
   2. two `++(<coordinate>)` which also describes a coordinate that is *relative* to the last absolute coordinate but also sets the new coordinate to be the next absolute coordinate.

   In your case, the differentation isn't important because your next coordinate `(minus.60)` is absolute anyway.

   The path `(c1) -- (c2) ++ (c3)` has two operations: One straight line from *c*<sub>1</sub> to *c*<sub>2</sub> and one *move to* (from *c*<sub>2</sub>) to *c*<sub>2</sub> + *c*<sub>3</sub>.

   If you want *c*<sub>2</sub> + *c*<sub>3</sub> to be the target of your path operation you need to specify **one** coordinate. This can be done with

   1. `([shift=(c2)] c3)`,
   2. `([shift=(c3)] c2)` or,
   3. with the `calc` library, `($(c2) + (c3)$)`

   I would also do the same for the starting coordinate, though usually it won't matter since in your case `(2-2)` is already part of the bounding box (yes, a move to updates the bounding box) and you don't decorate the path (some decorations do something with a move to you wouldn't want).
2. The `let … in` syntax is described in [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.15).

   `\p1` is actually `\p{1}` (i.e. it is possible to use everything, not just a digit: `\p{name}`).

   The `calc` library evaluates the specified coordinate and stores its *x* and *y* value (in the canvas coordinate system) in `\x{name}` and `\y{name}`, `\p{name}` expands then to `\x{name}, \y{name}`.
3. `.8*\x1` should work. Though, you also need to adjust `minus.60` then.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
$det = \begin{NiceArray}{ccc}
    u &           & v       \\
    x & \kern.1pt & x'      \\
    y & \kern.1pt & y'
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix|{2-1}{3-3}|
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (2-2.north) 
           -- 
           node[red,circle,inner sep=1pt] (minus) {$-$} 
           (3-2.south);
           
     \draw [red,->] 
           let \p1=($(minus.east)-(minus.center)$) in
           (2-2) ++(-6pt,2pt) % fine but maybe better:
                              % a. ([shift={(-6pt,2pt)}] 2-2)
                              % b. ($(2-2)+(-6pt,2pt)$)
           to[out=0,in=150]
           ([xshift=-.1*\x1]minus.60) % adjusting this also!
           arc[start angle=60,end angle=-240,radius=.8*\x1]
           to[out=30,in=180] 
           ([shift={(6pt,2pt)}] 2-2) % or with calc:
                                     % ($(2-2)+(6pt,2pt)$)
           % node[above left=2pt,scale=.2,black]{\p1}
           ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
= ...$
\end{document}
```

### Output

I've added a node with `\p1` as text in the output. In the code above that line is commented.

[image]

Comment: The first path can also be just `\node[…] at ($(2-2.north)!.5!(3-2.south)$) (minus){$-$};` if that seems more natural to write.

Comment: Thanks for all. I will have to ameliorate my code, but now I understand what I use.

Comment: +1 Great tutorial!

Comment: Congratulations for your 100k reputation achievement!

Comment: @egreg Mille grazie.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler version with some other corrections:

- Use option `first-row` so the matrix has the correct vertical placement.
- Use the built-in coordinates provided by `nicematrix`
- `\cdots`
- `vNiceArray` will place the delimiters automatically

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

$det = \begin{vNiceArray}{ccc}[first-row]
    u && v  \\
    x && x' \\
    &\color{red}-&\\
    y && y'
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, red, looseness=2](1.5-|2) to[out=0, in=0](3.5-|2.5) to[out=180, in=180] (1.5-|3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{vNiceArray}
= \cdots$

\end{document}
```

Or if you'd rather have only 2 rows and 2 columns, you can place the `-` as a node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

$det = \begin{vNiceArray}{c!{\hspace{5mm}}c}[first-row]
    u & v  \\
    x & x' \\[5mm]
    y & y'
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, red, looseness=2](1-1.east) to[out=0, in=0]($(2-1)!.5!(2-2)$)node[above=1mm]{$-$} to[out=180, in=180] (1-2.west|-1-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{vNiceArray}
= \cdots$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the minus sign is deliberately not put in a cell to make the decoration looks better. For `vNiceArray` and `first-row`, you are totally right: I was too confused by the problems with `TikZ`.

Comment: @projetmbc: I added an alternative. You can adjust the placement of the minus sign bu changing `above=1mm`.

Comment: Again, thank you, but I prefer the first solution which does not rely on the contents of the table. I did not indicate in my question, as it was not my problem, that one should take into account cases where one has for example `x` and `yyyyyy`.