# Connect two path without knowing the distance between them

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

Considering the following picture:

[image]

I would like to connect the two blue paths in order to obtain the red path like in the following picture:

[image]

But **I would like a solution where I don't have to know the horizontal length of the red path**, so Tikz will automatically calculate the good length instead of me.

### MWE

I tried something with coordinates but I obtain this result (I'm not able to "shift" the coordinates *(A)* and *(B)* vertically):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\myDistance}{1}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Preliminary node positionning
        \draw (0,0) node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance] (Nod0) {Node 0}%
        ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.2\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $) -- ++(0,2*\myDistance)%
        -- ++(\myDistance,0)%
        node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance cm,anchor=west] (Nod1) {Node 1}%
        (Nod1.east) -- ++(\myDistance,0)%
        node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance cm,anchor=west] (Nod2) {Node 2}%
        ;%
        
        % Two paths to connect
        \draw[blue] ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.8\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $) --  ++(0,\myDistance);%
        \draw[blue] ($ (Nod1) !.5! (Nod2) $) -- ++(0,-\myDistance);%
        
        \coordinate (A) at ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.8\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $)  +(0,\myDistance);
        \coordinate (B) at ($ (Nod1) !.5! (Nod2) $) +(0,-\myDistance);%
        
         \draw[red] (A) -- (B);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Why I don't want "absolute coordinates" ?

Because I want this graph to be easily modifiable, for example if I want to change the vertical and horizontal distance between *Node 0* and *Node 1*, I just have to change the *\myDistance* value and everything will be automatically adapted, no need to manually repositioning the blue paths for example because everything is positioned relatively to *Node 0*.

Comment: The `+(…)` isn't part of the coordinate specification, it's just a [move to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675226/16595). You'll need to pull that into the coordinate specification of the coordinate. For example `($ (Nod1) !.5! (Nod2) + (0,-\myDistance) $)`. Though, as you are already at these points in the previous paths, just defining the coordinates there is much easier.

Comment: You might be interested in the path operation [`|-` and `-|`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.2.2) as well as [something like `|-|`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172).

Comment: '|-|' is a very elegant solution thank you. I think I will use this one. BTW, I was not able to use '\usepackage{tikz-ext}' after manual installation on Miktex (Miktex can't find the *.sty* so I got an error when compiling) but I am able to load the 'ext.paths.ortho' library now (after manual installation of *tikz-ext* on Miktex) so it works fine! Also, I assume that the package *tikz-ext* should be loaded after the *tikz* package but it's not mentioned on the manual. Thank you very much again!

Comment: `tikz-ext` isn't a LaTeX package, it's a CTAN/TeXLive/MikTeX package (I don't like it either). You just need to load the library `\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.portho}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define two coordinates at the end of the blue paths, something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\myDistance}{1}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Preliminary node positionning
        \draw (0,0) node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance] (Nod0) {Node 0}%
        ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.2\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $) -- ++(0,2*\myDistance)%
        -- ++(\myDistance,0)%
        node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance cm,anchor=west] (Nod1) {Node 1}%
        (Nod1.east) -- ++(\myDistance,0)%
        node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=\myDistance cm,anchor=west] (Nod2) {Node 2}%
        ;%
        
        % Two paths to connect
        \draw[blue] ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.8\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $) --  ++(0,\myDistance) coordinate (A);% <----
        \draw[blue] ($ (Nod1) !.5! (Nod2) $) -- ++(0,-\myDistance) coordinate (B);% <----
        
%        \coordinate (A) at ($ (Nod0.north west)!0.8\myDistance!(Nod0.north east) $)  +(0,\myDistance);
%        \coordinate (B) at ($ (Nod1) !.5! (Nod2) $) +(0,-\myDistance);%
        
         \draw[red] (A) -- (B);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]